# Send a file from phone to laptop using bluetooth with bluez - don't work

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I want to send a file from my phone to my laptop. Both of them has bluetooth.

On the laptop I have `archlinux`. I have installed `bluez-5.35-1` for bluetooth management.

After installing, I typed:

```
systemctl enable bluetooth.service 
systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

Then, using `bluetoothctl` I started bluetooth by typing `power on`

Now, I can discover and pair the laptop from my phone.

I started the FTP server using:

```
systemctl --user start obex
```

On the phone, I tried to send a file, but I receive a message after a very short period `file not sent`.

In `journalctl -f` I can see the following logs:

```
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: CONNECT(0x0), (null)(0xffffffff)
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: CONNECT(0x0), (null)(0x0)
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: PUT(0x2), (null)(0xffffffff)
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: PUT(0x2), FORBIDDEN(0x43)
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: DISCONNECT(0x1), (null)(0xffffffff)
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: DISCONNECT(0x1), SUCCESS(0x20)
Oct 04 18:01:16 laptop obexd[8058]: disconnected: Transport got disconnected
```

I'm assuming that it's a permission issue since I can see that `FORBIDDEN` there. Where is the configuration file of `obexd` to see where it'll tries to save the file? I don't understand why `bluez` is so poor documented.

Anyone issued the same problems with bluetooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting obexd with the `-a` or `--auto-accept` option ("Automatically accept push requests") allows for pushing a file from the phone to the laptop.
This option skips the authorization request to the agent.